# string Validation with xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, django, validation, xlsxwriter

I am trying to put validations on excel file. I field should only accept characters or character with '_' symbol. The following code is only redistricting user to enter values more than length 10.

```
import xlsxwriter
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('staff.xlsx')
ws = workbook.add_worksheet()

ws.data_validation(1, 1, 10, 0,
                   {'validate': 'length',
                    'input_title': 'Enter value',
                    'criteria': '<',
                    'value': firstname_max_length,
                    'error_message': 'Max Length is{0}'.format(10)})
```

Help me to validate values that should only except characters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to work out how to do the data validation in Excel and then transfer it to XlsxWriter.

This will probably require a "Custom" data validation like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('staff.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

ws.data_validation('A1:C3',
                   {'validate': 'custom',
                    'value': '=ISTEXT(A1)',
                    'input_title': 'Enter a non numeric value',
                    'error_message': 'Enter a string not a number'})

wb.close()
```

Output:

[image]

However, this doesn't do exactly what you are looking for. It is still possible to add non character data or even strings like `123h` as shown in the screenshot. So you will need to figure out a formula that works in Excel and then apply it to XlsxWriter. I googled for an example but didn't find anything that worked.

Comment: I tried you code but its giving error message for every input value. Even i am entering only character then also it  not excepting. Please tell me where i am doing wrong?

This is what i tried- 

ws.data_validation('A1:A20',
                           {'validate': 'custom',
                            'value': '=ISTEXT(A1)',
                            'input_title': 'Enter a non numeric value',
                            'error_message': 'Enter a string not a number'})

Comment: I don’t know why it isn’t working for you. The screenshot above shows valid values in the specified range and an error message for and invalid value. So it is clearly working. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: It is working fine on Windows but not working on linux. Any help please.

Comment: What is "not working". The program or the output? If it is the output where is it not working? If the answer is something other than a version of Excel then are you sure that the application supports this feature?

Comment: the validation is not working on linux system but if the same file used on windows system the validation  working fine over there.

Comment: and can you help me with the formula that should strictly allow only string values now as you said it allowing Alphanumeric and symbols as well or can we use our costume function for validation at back-end?

Comment: *"the validation is not working on linux system"*. Again you don't say what is "not working" so I going to guess that you mean not working in OpenOffice or LibreOffice. If it works in Excel but doesn't work in those apps then it is an issue with those apps.

Comment: *"and can you help me with the formula that should strictly allow only string values "* No. Sorry. I don't know how to do that. That is really a separate question that you should ask since it isn't related to XlsxWriter or even Python.

Comment: If it works in Excel but doesn't work in LibreOffice then it is probably a LibreOffice issue. Or just a feature that it doesn't support. Either way it isn't an XlsxWriter issue.